# how to update new objects to a local storage

Tags: angular, ionic2

Hi i have a local storage and i would update it on button click, i am updating it but i am getting new arrays added up, i need only new objects to get added up

```
   logForm(form) {
        this.hideFooter = true;
        var EnteredName = form.value.name;
        var EnteredNumber = form.value.number;

       this.enteredContact.push({
            name: form.value.name,
            service: form.value.service,
            number:form.value.number
        })

        this.nativeStorage.getItem('contact') .then(
            data => {
            console.log(data)
            var empty = []
            empty.push(data);
            empty.push(this.enteredContact)
            console.log("entered date", this.enteredContact)
            this.nativeStorage.setItem('contact', this.enteredContact);
             this.nativeStorage.getItem('contact').then(
                    data =>{
                            this.ViewContacts = data;
                    })

        },
            error =>{
                 console.error(error.code);
                 if (error.code === 2) {
                     this.nativeStorage.setItem('contact', this.enteredContact);
                     this.nativeStorage.getItem('contact').then(
                        data =>{
                                this.ViewContacts = data;
                                this.disableReset = false
                                console.log("contact", data)
                            }
                     )
                 } else {

                 }
            }

        );
    }
```

i am getting like this:
[image]

I need pure objects like this

[image]

I am creating a something similar to a phone book i would get name,number,occupation and i need to store it an then show that storage list .

what happens with this updated code is i could able to store data but when i move back a page and if i come again the storage gets to 0

Comment: Instead of Push, use asign (=)

Comment: Then explain better  your issue

Comment: That's not the issue, but your app purpose. Explain what you are really trying to achieve with the code above. Why you need next and previous objects(values)?

Comment: i am using the same local storage to store and view data, when new data is been updated, in the contact list view i have to show previously added contact and the new current contact @Vega

Answer (score 0):

Try something as the following:

```
        data => {
            let dataArray = data;
            dataArray.unshift(form.value); //this will add at the start
            if dataArray.length>2{
                  dataArray.pop(); // this will remove the last one
            }
            this.nativeStorage.setItem('contact', data);
        },...
```

The purpose of this is to insure you always have the second element as the previous contact and the first one the newest.

Comment: where do i have to use this

Comment: i tried this but its not working, please the updated code @vega